# PyCharm Code Folding/Outlining Generates Wrong Boundaries

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm having a very frustrating issue with PyCharm in that it does not want to properly outline the code so that blocks fold correctly. I've looked all over the place and couldn't find any help with this particular problem. In a nutshell, PyCharm seems to decide on skewed block boundaries so that the blocks fold up on each other. It's quite irritating. Any thoughts?

## **Example of Incorrect Folding Behavior:**

[image: Code to be folded]

Trying to collapse `_get_thread_name` yields this:
[image]

## **Example of Correct Folding Behavior:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I get the same issue, usually clicking the up arrow at the bottom of the function works for me

Comment: Try restarting it. When stuff goes crazy that usually fixes it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Unfortunately the problem persists after restart, but clicking the up arrow at the bottom did work! I am really curious what the root cause is...

Comment: A workaround that I use is to cut the problematic code and paste it back in the same spot. This seems to cause a refresh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally!! I figured out how to remove the invalid folding regions. If you place your cursor on the line that starts an invalid folding block (*line 106 in my first example*), then right click anywhere in that line and select `Folding -> Fold Selection / Remove Region` and that will delete the incorrect folding annotation!

I still have no clue why they are generated in the first place, but at least this is a decent "fix".

Comment: It might be worth noting that the keyboard shortcut for this is `ctrl` `.`

Comment: Not working for me in PyCharm 2019.3. This issue is so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
# region FooRegion
  ...
  your-code-here
  ...
# endregion
```

This will create code folding regions manually like in visual studio style