# Pycharm folding issue

Tags: python, pycharm, fold

In Pycharm, when defining a function in Python, the fold block automatically includes the next line below the function. How do I get rid of this issue?

For example: `root = Tk()` is included in the fold when it shouldn't be

[image: "root = Tk()" is included in the fold when it shouldn't be]

Comment: I can replicate this issue. This question appears to be the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52803543/8061009) but that one does not explain how this bug is caused, and is unanswered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm Code Folding/Outlining Generates Wrong Boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803543/pycharm-code-folding-outlining-generates-wrong-boundaries). Flagging as a duplicate now since the linked question has an answer that removes the problem (but not permanently).